# True or False: If $A + A^2$ is invertible, then $A$ is also invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is a square $n$ by $n$ matrix here.

I understand the proof for $A^2$ being invertible given that $A$ is invertible, but I fail to see how to incorporate the $A + A^2$ factor into it.

What I have tried so far is a rough factoring to give:

$A(I_n + A)$

But that is where I am stuck. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This site uses [MathJax formatting of formulas](//math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). More tips [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). *(autocomment)*

Comment: You've factored it. Now try multiplying by the inverse. Can you use that to get an inverse for $A$?

Comment: @MattSamuel by left-multiplying %A^-1% I get:

Comment: Well you don't know $A$ has an inverse yet. Try multiplying on the right by the inverse of $A+A^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $A+A^2$ is invertible exist $B$ such that $(A+A^2)B=I\to A(I+A)B=I$ and then $A^{-1}=(I+A)B$ ie, $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Is it by the definition $AA^-1 = I_n$ that you arrive to that conclusion? The proof makes sense, but it's the method that I am lost on

Comment: Yes, A has inverse B iff AB=I

Comment: @AdamM. An inverse is defined to be a matrix $M$ such that $AM=MA=I$.  There is a theorem, probably proved in your textbook, that if $A$ is a square matrix, and $AM=I$, then $M$ is automatically an inverse for $A$. (Note: Inverses are unique, but we don't actually need that fact here)

Comment: Observe that if there exist D and E with AD=I=EA then D=E  (and hence AD=DA=I) because E=EI=E(AD)=(EA)D=ID=D.  So if (A+A^2)P=i=Q(A+A^2) then let D=(I+A)P and E=Q(I+A).......

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Note that $A+A^2=A(I+A)$. For the Binet rule:

$0\neq \det(A+A^2)=\det(A)\det(I+A)\Longrightarrow \det(A)\neq 0$.

Comment: I'm a little bit lost on your last step there. How did you arrive that the determinant of A is zero?

Comment: It's because if $det(A)$ were 0, then $det(A+A^2) = 0$, which it is not since $A+A^2$ is invertible.

Comment: @AdamM. The product of two real numbers is nonzero if and only if the two numbers are nonzero.  By taking determinants, it follows that $MN$ is invertible if and only if $M$ and $N$ are invertible.  Vin is applying this to $M=A$, $N=I+A$.

Comment: Nice answer @Vin.Zaccaro's +1

Answer (score 3):

Recall that a matrix is invertible if and only if it has a trivial nullspace.  Suppose $A+A^2$ is invertible.  We will prove that the nullspace of $A$ is $\{0\}$.

Suppose $Ax = 0$.  Then, $Ax+A(Ax) = 0 + A0 = 0$.  But, $Ax+A(Ax) = (A+A^2)x$, and since $A+A^2$ was assumed to be invertible, it must be that $x = 0$.  Thus, the nullspace of $A$ is $\{0\}$, so $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

This will be true for every ring: if $a+a^2$ is invertible then so is $a$. It follows from another general fact: if $ab$ has a right inverse and $ca$ has a left inverse then $a$ is invertible. Indeed, $(a b) b_1=1$ implies $a(b b_1) = 1$ and $c_1 (ca) = 1$ implies $(c_1 c) a= 1$, so $a$ has both left and right inverses and so they coincide ( standard proof) and $a$ is invertible.

Now, to the proof of the statement. If $a+a^2$ is invertible then $a(1+a)$ is invertible and $(1+a)a$ is invertible, and by the above it follows that $a$ itself is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

This is a direct consequence of:

> **Proposition.** Let $M$ denote a [Dedekind-finite](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2010/09/17/dedekind-finite-rings/) monoid. Then:
>
> - For all $a,b \in M$, if $ab$ is invertible, then so too are $a$ and $b$.
> - In other words, the invertible elements of $M$ form a [saturated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicatively_closed_set) submonoid of $M$.

*Proof.* Suppose $ab$ is invertible. We will show that $a$ is invertible. Since $ab$ is invertible, We can find $k$ with $(ab)k=1$. So $a(bk)=1$. So by Dedekind-finiteness, we have that $a$ is invertible.

Returning to your problem, we use the fact that for all natural numbers $n$, the matrix ring $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is Dedekind-finite. Now, we know that

$$A+A^2 = A(I+A)$$

and it is given that the LHS is invertible. Hence by the above proposition, both $A$ and $I+A$ are invertible.

Comment: One has to be careful, the proposition is not valid in general. There are monoids $M$ with two elements $a$, $b$ so that $ab =1$ but $ba \ne 1$.

Comment: @orangeskid, okay, its fixed now.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I downvoted simply because there is no way the person who asked the question can get anything out of your answer.

Comment: @Artem, I actually had an interesting conversation about the sentiment you express in the above message last night, over no fewer than three glasses of red. The topic of the conversation was: "Are direct answers best?" My friend and I didn't reach any concrete conclusions, but we both ended up agreeing that in a world where you can Google search any term you don't understand, we should feel free to try introducing the OP to relevant ideas that they may be unfamiliar with.